# How do I print a value from an instance of 'User' in a flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
class User {
 String token;
 User({this.token});
} 

class AuthService {
final String url = 'https://reqres.in/api/login';
final controller = StreamController<User>();

Future<User> signIn(String email, String password) async {
final response =
    await post(url, body: {'email': email, 'password': password});
final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
final user = _userFromDatabaseUser(data);
// print(user.token);
controller.add(user);
return user;
}

//create user obj based on the database user
User _userFromDatabaseUser(Map user) {
return user != null ? User(token: user['token']) : null;
}

//user stream for provider
Stream<User> get user {
 return controller.stream;
}
}
//in Sign in page 
onPressed: () async {
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
 dynamic result = await _auth.signIn(email, password);
 print(result); // Instance of 'User'                                        
 }
}
```

I am new to flutter and want to make an app that only authenticated users. I'm trying to read user token data from a stream. then check that token is not null if I got token then goto home page otherwise it will show error how do I  print or store token value?

Answer (score 1):

You can do is when you get the user after the sign In:

```
 User result = await _auth.signIn(email, password);
```

Then to see the data you can do is

```
print(result.token);
```

which will give you the token, and then you can use the shared prefrences to store your token and access it.
Check out the docs for the it: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Answer (score 0):

You can `override` [Object.toString](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Object/toString.html) method.

you can add this method in your `User` class to print the token instead of `Instance of 'User'`.

```dart
@override
String toString() {
   // TODO: change the below return to your desired string
   return "token: $token";
}
```

Comment: still got token: null value.

Comment: have you made sure that token is in the `response` variable but still it prints token: null?

Comment: @Yashwant I updated my code you can check my post. It still null

Comment: @JamesMaddinson I would suggest that after you perform `jsonDecode` in your `signIn` function `print` the data variable and make sure token has value

Comment: @Yashwant I am sure it's a print token. When I try to get value in sign-in widget it shows null.

Answer (score 0):

> You can print using
>
> ```
> print(userModel.toString());
> ```